# How make One-to-Many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Who can tell how to make a model in this situations. One employee earlier (until today, there is a date of dismissal) could hold several positions, but now they can only hold one position (there is no date of dismissal).

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateQuit { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    [Key]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need to add to the class Position next code?

```
public Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

Do I need add to Employee class next code?

```
public int PositionId { get; set; }
```

and іs it necessary to make a method OnModelCreating?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Employees)
            .WithOne(e => e.Position);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework 6.x or EF Core? Please confirm!

Comment: More importantly your explanation is not clear. Are you expecting one employee to have multiple position at time or one employee to have one position at a time?

Comment: one employee hold one position and i use EF Core

Comment: Can one position be assigned to multiple employees?

Comment: Of course can)I have only one limit - is that there should not be situations where one employee hold many positions

Comment: Okay! Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you are expecting one employee to have one position but one position can have multiple employees at a time. In a nutshell its `one-to-many` between `Position` and `Employee`.

So you can do as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateQuit { get; set; }

    public Position Position { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    [Key]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Position)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.PositionId);
}
```

To learn more about EF Core relationships: [EF Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 1):

1. *Do I need to add to the class Position next code?*

First, it should be `public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }`.

Second, it is optional. If you ever want to know who are the employees for a certain position, you can add it.

2. *Do I need add to Employee class next code?*

Yes. That is the foreign key that defines the relationship between the two entities.

3. *Is it necessary to make a method OnModelCreating?*

Yes, because then the model is appropriately configured in EntityFramework.

---

If you want to have the employee list in the position entity, it should be something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Position>()
    .HasMany<Employee>(g => g.Employees)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Position)
    .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.PositionId);
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasRequired<Position>(s => s.Position)
    .WithMany(g => g.Employees)
    .WithForeignKey<int>(s => s.PositionId);
```

If you don't need the employee list in the position entity, it should be something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasRequired<Position>(s => s.Position)
    .WithMany()
    .WithForeignKey<int>(s => s.PositionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

add foreign key of Position table in Employee

```
   public class Employee
        {
            [Key]
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public Position Position { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateQuit { get; set; }
            public int PositionId { get; set; }
            public virtual Position Position { get; set;}
        }
```

then add icollection of employees in position table

```
 public class Position
    {
        [Key]
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }  

    }
```